# is there a way to have an animated talking characher in React Native?

Tags: react-native

I need to make an animated talking character in a React Native app. is it possible ? If yes, what is the best way to achieve it ?

Comment: Try to ask in a more specific way,
Is there a specific character you want to animate?

Comment: I have to make a character and it has to be animated and able to talk.